# Capturar valor do último INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou criando um sistema de notícia onde o usuário tem a opção de cadastra a notícia e colocar o link original onde a noticia foi gerada, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que eu quero que o usuário tenha a opção de cadastrar a notícia com o própio link da notícia que será gerado, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
        $urlNoticia = "index.php?".PARAMETER_NAME_ACTION."=show&";
        $urlNoticia .= PARAMETER_NAME_FILE."=exibir_noticia";
        $urlNoticia .= "&noticia_id=".$model->getnoticia_id();

        if(isset($_POST['FLinkNoticia'])) {
            $error = $this->getConexao()->executeNonQuery($sql);            
            $sqll  = "UPDATE noticia SET not_link = '".URL.$urlNoticia."SELECT MAX(noticia_id) FROM noticia' ";
            $sqll .= "WHERE not_titulo = '".$model->getnot_titulo()."'";
            $error = $this->getConexao()->executeNonQuery($sqll);
        } else {
            $error = $this->getConexao()->executeNonQuery($sql);
        }
```

**FLinkNoticia** é um checkbox.

Na primeira `$error` ele faz o insert no banco, e logo após ele deve fazer um `UPDATE`, ele até que realiza o `UPDATE` mas não traz o ID da notícia, apenas o URL

Comment: vc quer pegar o `id` da tabela no update?

Comment: Isso, eu quero pega o último `id` inserido ! @rray

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida. Você já não possui o valor do id antes de fazer o update? Aliás porque você não usa o id da notícia no where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função LAST_INSERT_ID() do mysql que retornará o útlimo id inserido.
Coloque esse trecho logo após seu insert depois da variável $error

$ultimoId = $this->getConexao()->executeNonQuery('LAST_INSERT_ID()');

Comment: Como o SGBD vai saber qual o último ID se o nome do campo é diferente ?

Comment: Não entendi @IkaroSales, independente do nome do campo o servidor retorna o valor do campo que é chave primária na tabela, essa informação está disponível nos metadados da tabela ou DML